# clone function change the value of object and copied object creates reference?

Tags: php, clone

```
   $objM1= new clsData(22,33);

   $objM2= clone $objM1;

   $objM2->setData(4,5);
```

Do the values of `$objM1` change?

Comment: What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: Cant you really check?

Comment: just print_r() all the objects and see what happens. BTW clone does not create object by reference and it was the problem before clone.

Comment: $objM1= new clsData(22,33);
$objM2= clone $objM1;
$objM1->getData();
$objM2->getData();
$objM2->setData(4,5);  // after this values of $objM2 and $objM1 are same?
$objM1->getData();
$objM2->getData();

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty agree with u

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe.* That depends on how the class is implemented.

`clone` makes a *shallow* copy of the object. That means it will create another object of the same type, and then copy all the attributes over. If such an attribute is an object, then your cloned parent object will refer to the same object instance as the original. So if you're modifying that object, this will reflect across both objects.

Another possibility would be that `setData` sets `static` properties instead of instance properties, in which case the change will also reflect across both instances.

However, if you're just setting integer properties on the object, those will be independent for the two instances.